# Export data from Mysql and output to CSV allow save as

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

i want to export my data from mysql and export it to CSV (allow download) OR email it out.

Problem : the CSV file is empty. When the download started, the file is empty..

```
<?php
    require_once("../dbconnection/dbcon.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['download']))
{
    $filName = "customer.csv";
    $objWrite = fopen("customer.csv", "w");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
    {
        fwrite($objWrite, "\"$objResult[username]\",\"$objResult[password]\",\"$objResult[name]\",");
        fwrite($objWrite, "\"$objResult[email]\",\"$objResult[role]\",\"$objResult[satus]\" \n");
    }
    fclose($objWrite);
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
    // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    //header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    //header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filName");

}

exit;
?>
```

my code for sending the CSV as email works

```
<?php
$filName = "customer.csv";
$objWrite = fopen("customer.csv", "w");

require_once("../dbconnection/dbcon.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$run=mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
    fwrite($objWrite, "\"$objResult[username]\",\"$objResult[password]\",\"$objResult[name]\",");
    fwrite($objWrite, "\"$objResult[email]\",\"$objResult[role]\",\"$objResult[satus]\" \n");
}
fclose($objWrite);

//*************** Send Email ***************//

$strTo = "my email";
$strSubject = "CSV Report";
$strMessage = "Download $filName for CSV Report";

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: RecruitMate | Murdoch University<recruitmate.mur@gmail.com>\nReply-To: recruitmate.mur@gmail.com\n";


$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-874\n"; // or UTF-8 //
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

$strContent1 = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$filName")));
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filName."\"\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent1."\n\n";

$flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader); // @ = No Show Error //
if($flgSend)
{
echo "CSV Generated & Email Sending.";
}
else
{
echo "Email Can Not Send.";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're outputting nothing to browser except headers. What do you expect?

Comment: hmm. then what should i output?

Comment: Did you look at the PHP Error log. I would think you will see quite a few things to fix in there

Comment: You should output contents of the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i execute download.php, there is no error log.. it pop up to download my csv file.

Comment: @u_mulder could u give me some example or modification to my code

Comment: You could start by fixing `$objResult[username]` to `$objResult['username']` and so on for all the data from the database or rather `{$objResult['username']}`

Comment: Content type for a csv file is `text/csv` not `application/csv`

Comment: @RiggsFolly after adding the '', i get errors


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/empresst/public_html/kearts/recruitmate/admin/download.php on line 14

Comment: And please learn about [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), PHP's built-in function for writing lines to a CSV file..... your homebrew is seriously flawed

Comment: And please, please don't tell me that you're storing passwords in plaintext and then sending them across the internet in plaintext e-mail attachments

Comment: Did you check that the file you create actally has any data in it?

Comment: @MarkBaker my password is stored as sha1.. i am just trying the export csv works then i will change my sql query...

Comment: @MarkBaker do you have to be so crude in the way u reply? cant u give people a chance to learn?

Comment: Telling you the correct content type to use, telling you about a built-in PHP function that does what your code fails to do correctly - that's trying to help you learn

Comment: Advising you about a security flaw in what you're doing is a serious warning, trying to help you learn

Comment: i have change my code to this and it work

if(isset($_POST['download']))
{
 require_once("../dbconnection/dbcon.php"); 
 $filename = "toy_csv.csv";
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');


 header('Content-type: application/csv');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);


 $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
 }
 exit;
}

Comment: Yay, you're using `fputcsv()`... that means you don't need to worry about commas or quotes in your data, because fputcsv() will handle them correctly

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned - your code for downloading does nothing except sending headers.  But you don't send file contents. The easiest way is to use `readfile`:

```
// some headers here
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filName");
readfile($filName);
exit;
```